# Properly formatting Outlook links in org-html-export

Tags: org-export

I've followed a solution found at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/71786/can-i-create-a-link-to-a-specific-email-message-in-outlook) for capturing the unique identifier (UID) of an Outlook message stored in a PST file, and creating a org link of the form:

```
[[outlook:UID][Message subject]]
```

Selecting this link in emacs opens the message in Outlook using a little Lisp stored as `org-outlook.el` in my `.emacs.d/lisp` directory, so I can access specific messages right from org. Really nice solution for integrating emails that I need to reference right from my notes.

The problem is that I also like to export my notes as html using `org-html-export` through `C-c C-e h o`, but the Outlook links get rendered as:

```
<a href="UID">Message subject</a>
```

which tries (and fails, of course) to open a local file named "UID" instead of:

```
<a href="outlook:UID">Message subject</a>
```

which my browser correctly passes off to Outlook.

Is there a way for me to custom define the link export format for an `outlook:` link? Kinda a newbie here, and I couldn't find anything on the topic.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `org-add-link-type` or `org-link-set-parameters` in `org-outlook.el`? The former is deprecated in recent versions of org-mode.

Comment: @Nick - the author of `org-outlook.el` -- posted a few years back in response to a question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/71786/can-i-create-a-link-to-a-specific-email-message-in-outlook) --  used `org-add-link-type`, which, as for as I saw in the org manual did not have an `export:` function.  So glad you pointed me to the revised capability of `org-link-set-parameters` - that was the ticket! - I revised `org-outlook.el` to use `follow:` and `export:` and it works like a champ.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, `org-add-link-type` takes a second optional argument called `export`, so you might have been able to do it with that, but it's certainly better to change it to the modern idiom.

Answer (score 2):

See comment from @Nick

For anyone interested; I modified `org-outlook.el` from what is shown at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/71786/can-i-create-a-link-to-a-specific-email-message-in-outlook) to be:

```
;; old: 
;; (org-add-link-type "outlook" 'org-outlook-open)

;; new:
(org-link-set-parameters
 "outlook"
 :follow (lambda (path) (org-outlook-open path))
 :export (lambda (path desc backend)
           (cond
            ((eq 'html backend)
             (format "<a href=\"outlook:%s\">%s</a>" path desc)))))
```

Thanks again for the hint from @Nick - not sure how to give him credit for the answer since he provided feedback in a comment.

Comment: You have given me more than enough credit, given that you did all the work! You might want to add a pointer in the superuser question pointing back to this - and if there is an upstream repo for org-outlook.el, maybe open an issue, pointing back to your solution.